# Put "hand-made" response in cache

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I'm trying to add some offline capabilities to my web app. Under certain circumstances, I want to fetch the data from a request/response in the cache, change it, and add it back to the cache as a new request/response pair.

So far, I've been able to get the data from the cache and modify it, but when I put it in the cache, I get an empty cache entry (Content-Length: 0). **EDIT:** Actually, Chrome Developer Tools show, in the preview pane, the correct object, but in the cache entries list it says "Content-Length: 0" and "Time Cached: 1/1/1970 0:59:59".

And then, when trying to fetch it again from the cache, I get a no-match error, and cache.match() returns undefined.

This is what I have so far:

```
return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
    return cache.matchAll().then(function(responses) {
        var resp = responses[0].clone();
        return resp.clone().json().then(function (datosResp) {

            var nuevaMed = nuevaMedicionDesdeMedicion(datosResp);
            var urlACachear = new URL('obra/' + nuevaMed.obraId + '/mediciones/' + nuevaMed.id, urlBase);

            var nuevaMedJSON = JSON.stringify(nuevaMed);
            var blob1 = new Blob([nuevaMedJSON], { type: "application/json;charset=utf-8" });
            var myHeaders = new Headers(resp.headers);

            var resACachear = new Response(blob1, { "status": 200, myHeaders });

            return cache.put(urlACachear, resACachear.clone()).then(function() {
                // Whatever...
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Is it even possible to store and correctly retrieve my own requests and responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Time Cached: 1/1/1970 0:59:59` is a known [bug in Chrome's DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747718). I'd imagine that the `Content-Length: 0` is the same bug.

What you describe sounds like your new `Response` is being properly written to the cache, but there's something wrong with the your call to `match()` that is preventing you from finding the cached entry.

As a quick sanity check, you can run the following code in the JS console to get a list of all the URLs used as keys in your `CACHE_NAME` cache. Make sure that you see the URLs you expect to be cached printed out, and then explicitly try performing a `match()` using one of those URLs.

```
const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
const requests = await cache.keys();
const urls = requests.map(request => request.url);
console.log(urls):
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response... I had to set this aside for a while... Yes, it seems like it was stored correctly regardless of the date and content-length being incorrect, and the not matching issue was due to a double slash in the URL I was trying to match...